# 2-sample independent t-test where each of two columns is in different data frame

Tags: r, t-test

I need to run a 2-sample independent t-test, comparing Column1 to Column2. But Column1 is in DataframeA, and Column2 is in DataframeB. How should I do this?

Just in case relevant (feel free to ignore): I am a true beginner. My experience with R so far has been limited to running 2-sample matched t-tests within the same data frame by doing the following:

```
t.test(response ~ Column1, 
data = (Dataframe1 %>% 
gather(key = "Column1", value = "response", "Column1", "Column2")),
paired = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

---

`t_test_result = t.test(DataframeA$Column1, DataframeB$Column2, paired=TRUE)`

### Explanation

---

If the data is paired, I assume that both dataframes will have the same number of observations (same number of rows). You can check this with `nrow(DataframeA) == nrow(DataframeB)` .

You can think of each column of a dataframe as a vector (an ordered list of values). The way that you have used `t.test` is by using a formula (`y~x`), and you were essentially saying: Given the dataframe specified in `data`, perform a t test to assess the significance in the difference in means of the variable `response` between the paired groups in `Column1`.

Another way of thinking about this is by grabbing the data in `data` and separating it into two vectors: the vector with observations for the first group of `Column1`, and the one for the second group. Then, for each vector, you compute the mean and stdev and apply the appropriate formula that will give you the t statistic and hence the p value.

Thus, you can just extract those 2 vectors separately and provide them as arguments to the `t.test()` function. I hope it was beginner-friendly enough ^^ otherwise let me know

---

EDIT: a few additions
(I was going to reply in the comments but realized I did not have space hehe)

Regarding the what @Ashish did in order to turn it into a Welch's test, I'd say it was to set `var.equal = FALSE`. The `paired` parameter controls whether the t-test is run on paired samples or not, and since your data frames have unequal number of rows, I'm suspecting the observations are not matched.

As for the Cohen's d effect size, [you can check this stats exchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151781/cohens-d-calculation-in-r?rq=1), from which I copy the code:

For context, m1 and m2 are the group's means (which you can get with `n1 = mean(DataframeA$Column1)`), s1 and s2 are the standard deviations (`s2 = sd(DataframeB$Column2)`) and n1 and n2 the sample sizes (`n2 = length(DataframeB$Column2)`)

```
lx <- n1- 1 # Number of observations in group 1
ly <- n2- 1 # # Number of observations in group 1

md  <- abs(m1-m2)        ## mean difference (numerator)
csd <- lx * s1^2 + ly * s2^2
csd <- csd/(lx + ly)
csd <- sqrt(csd)                     ## common sd computation

cd  <- md/csd                        ## cohen's d
```

Comment: The dataframes actually don't have the same number of observations. But their variance is equal. So I'd like to use a student's t-test, rather than Welch's. Any advice on how to do that? (When I change paired=TRUE to instead be paired=FALSE, it runs a Welch's t-test, as did Ashish Baid's suggested approach, below.) Otherwise this was fantastically helpful and informative--thank you!

Comment: Also I'd like to calculate the Cohen's d with respect to the results of the t-test. Any advice?

Comment: I edited the answer to include your new questions ^^ It'd be helpful if you marked it as the answer, to let other people know it has been answered

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
res = t.test(DataFrameA$Column1, DataFrameB$Column2, alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = FALSE)
```

Comment: how is this different from the other answer posted?